# get bootstrap modal element id on hide.bs.modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to return the element ID of the currently being hidden modal in bootstrap. I cannot seem to find a way to capture this via this code:

```
$(document).on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {

     // I want to know what the attr ID is of THIS modal being closed?
     // I tried console.log(e) to see if I could find the reference but its not in the object?

});
```

The purpose is to have this for all modals, some modals contain input fields, if changed to a dirty flag I can alert the user that data loss may occur if they close this modal.

Comment: tried $(this).attr('id') ?

Comment: Isn't `e.target` the modal being closed...? https://jsfiddle.net/gc4e9d2x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log the event you receive inside that handler function, you'll notice there is a `target` node on their that contains the actual modal. So getting the id should be as simple as:

```
var id = e.target.id;
```

have a look at the demo I set up:
http://www.bootply.com/JvORc5bWvD
On close you'll see the modal id in the console.

Comment: Ok, I see now. for some reason I was getting an empty target {}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can see here I was getting an empty target when I was stringifying the return.  However, if I alert (e.target.id) it returns the proper id.  Thanks!